# How to get exact pattern which has specific word by using Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a question for you. I write simple regex but it didn't work way that what I want.

My regex:

```
/^\bname\b="([^"]*)"$/
```

But it did not work. So I decided to change that regex to this:

```
/name="([^"]*)"$/
```

this is perfectly fine to me when I have just one match case. In other words, This is working fine this case:

```
let my_case = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"';
let result = my_case.match(/name="([^"]*)"$/);
console.log(result);
```

but when I change case string to like this:

```
let my_case = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relatedFile"; filename="article_217605.pdf"';
let result = my_case.match(/name="([^"]*)"$/);
console.log(result);
```

Result be like:

```
[
  'name="article_217605.pdf"',
  'article_217605.pdf',
  index: 24,
  input: 'name="relatedFile"; filename="article_217605.pdf"',
  groups: undefined
]
```

I don't wanna this actually. I want to get (name="relatedFile") how to get this in this case? pls help me!

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `let case =` ? case seems a reserved word.

Comment: @Thefourthbird sorry about that I am just write as example. Okey I will edit this post

Comment: I think you want `\bname="([^"]*)"` with a word boundary right? If you want the full match only, you can omit the capture group as well `/\bname="[^"]*"/`

Comment: @Thefourthbird ooh thank god. My bad pls provide your answer below. I will make it approved answer

Comment: There is no typo here, and it is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `^\bname\b="([^"]*)"$` does not match as it asserts the start and the end of the string. In a pattern like this, the word boundaries `\b` are also implicit and can be omitted from the pattern.

This pattern that you tried `name="([^"]*)"$` will allow a partial match starting with name and then will only match as it can assert the end of the string and will give you the wrong match.

If you would start that pattern with a word boundary, there will still be no match because it will then not allow a partial match anymore.

You could start the match with a word boundary and then capture in group 1 the value between double quotes without using any of the other anchors.

```
\bname="([^"]*)"
```

See the match on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mTfdOj/1).

Answer (score 0):

- Since it's a string
- Instead of regex you can split and map element for this case

```js
let somecase = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relatedFile"; filename="article_217605.pdf"';

let res = somecase.split(";").map(ele => ele)[1];
console.log(res)
```

- Using Regex

```js
let somecase = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relatedFile"; filename="article_217605.pdf"';

let res = somecase.split(";").find(ele => /name=.*/g.test(ele));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: well it's working perfect. But I want to use regex  so ...

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal I updated the answer with regex please check might :)

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly correct answer. By the way thank you to answering my question @The fourth bird.

His answer is:

```
/\bname="[^"]*"/
```

But it doesn't work well because result couldn't give me name value. So I change it little bit.

Correct perfect answer is:

```
/\bname="([^"]*)"/
```

thank you guys! I am really appreciate it.